Gable Attic Fan(s) Not Working
I am trying to replace a gable attic fan that came up on our home inspection as being defective.
I am having a bit of an issue though. I have purchased and installed two different fans now of two different brands (MaxxAir and Broan).
I have confirmed through a multi-meter that I have power all the way to the motor, on both units. Both thermostats were triple checked to be wired correctly per the manual. However neither fan is turning on.
Is there something that I am missing here? I initially replaced the first one thinking that the motor was defective from the factory. But now after having the same issue, I’m confused. The attic is definitely hot enough to trip the thermostat, and I can hear the switch on the thermostat engaging when I turn the dial through the temperature range.
I have 120V leaving the thermostat going to the motor and using a non contact digital tester, I have power indicated through the wiring and at the motor. All wiring was done per the manufacturer’s installation manual. It’s literally screwing in a ground wire, and connecting the hot/neutral.

do the fans turn on when plugged into a different electrical outlet? ... if you install a light bulb in place of the fan, does it light?

If power to the motor, the motor should turn.  It is only a switch/thermostat that stops power to the motor.  Is the power at the motor or thermostat?

Please revise to provide more detail about your wiring and hardware. Also mention what your meter told you, specifically. There's not much to go on here. See [ask] and take the [tour] for tips.

I will try plugging in one of the fans to a different outlets. I have 120v coming to the thermostat from the house wiring, I have 120V leaving the thermostat going to the motor and using a non contact digital tester, I have power indicated through the wiring and at the motor. All wiring was done per the manufacturer’s installation manual. It’s literally screwing in a ground wire, and connecting the hot/neutral.

Wondering if there might be a safety breaker on the motor that is popped out.

Sounds like you're observing the difference between actual, measured-with-a-meter 120 volts vs the much more vague and uncertain "the non-contact voltage tester lit up" measurement.

It sounds like you have dropped the neutral. You may have power, but no path for it to return.
Use a multimeter to see if you have 120v between the hot and neutral at the fan motor. If not, you need to trace back until you find where the neutral is lost. At the tstadt is a good guess.

Thank You for an actual answer, I will look into this
